# REST API Design with many input parameters including collections

Tags: rest

I need to design and implement a REST API where users need to pass many input parameters. Out of those input parameters few are collection of an integer, few of them are date strings etc. After getting all these parameters I need to return unique id in the response. What method type (PUT, POST or GET) I should use in order to implement this API? How can I pass all these parameters to the API? I don't want users to format input parameter list into XML or JSON and post as a request body.

I appreciate if anybody can help on this topic.

Comment: Can you add some specifics about the various parameters and API functions?

Comment: @Adam: Like I mentioned in the question, there are few integer collections plus few string variables. Few string variables will contain datetime stamp. API will receiver this data, store it in the database and return a unique id to the user in the response.

Answer (score 1):

`POST` is for creating new resources.

`PUT` is for updating existing resources. A `PUT` call should be idempotent, i.e. issuing the same request twice will end in no side effects.

To get an overall clue on how RESTful services work, [read this article](http://tomayko.com/writings/rest-to-my-wife).

And yes, if you want your users to submit a complex set of parameters JSON/XML is the best way to go of course.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Is there any alternative than JSON/XML as input to API. I don't want to add burden to my API users to format all the input parameters into XML/JSON.

Comment: As an API user I don't see it as a burden but more as a relief. How else were you planning to provide interaction with your API? I mean, you could use any other data interchange format like yaml, but I think your problem would be the same.

Comment: Well, complex data should be formatted. If you know a better solution to JSON/XML, feel free to use it : )) Those are common methods of serialization, can be validated before sending, and are de facto standard after all - honestly I can't see a better choice at the moment.

Comment: So do you mean method-type = POST and json/xml formatted payload (input parameters) in the request is better choice?

Comment: You are not providing any alternative : )) So it is the best by definition.

Comment: I don't know any alternative that's why I posted my problem on this forum :). I know that we can always post data in the form of xml/json but I wanted to avoid that way.